# How to select latest object from each group using Django and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

I want to select latest Post of a User of each type. My model is like this:

```
class UserPost(models.Model):

    POST_CHOICES = (
        ('image', 'Image'),
        ('text', 'Text'),
        ('video', 'Video')
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_type = models.CharField(choices=POST_CHOICES, max_length=10)
    posted_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

I know it can be done using this query:

```
UserPost.objects.values('post_type').annotate(date=Max('posted_at'))
```

But this only returns 2 columns (`post_type`, `date`), and I want more than 2 columns.

I was able to achieve this in the MySQL with the following query:

```
SELECT P1.post_type, 
       P1.post_id, 
       P1.posted_at 
FROM   appname_userpost P1, 
       (SELECT post_type, 
               Max(posted_at) AS max_posted_at 
        FROM   appname_userpost 
        GROUP  BY post_type) AS P2 
WHERE  P1.posted_at = P2.max_posted_at 
       AND P1.post_type = P2.post_type 
       AND user_id = 97;
```

How can I achieve these same results using Django?

Answer (score 1):

You can add whatever column you need in `values` like this below:

```
UserPost.objects.values('post_type', 'post_id', 'posted_at').annotate(date=Max('posted_at'))
```